# Testing In app purchase using IAB helper class

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

Hi Im trying to test in app purchase in my app. It seems that everything has been setup properly but when im trying to purchase an item im getting the following:

> "error processing purchase df-ppa-40"

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: I remember to have an identical issue a few months ago. What I did? I searched for `Google Services Framework` application at the application manager and then I clicked "Clear data" and "Clear cache". It worked for me!

Comment: Did it already.. No success

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I have no more ideas! The more I can tell you is to debug and check what's the specific error that comes from Google's server to have better details about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem. This error occurs if you try to purchase yourself product - a product that has been added by you in the developers console. Once tried the purchase flow with dummy tester account(and not myself account) the flow passed successfully.